# Most efficient way to find unique entries in a large data set

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search, arraylist

Before anything, I am making it clear that this is an assignment and I do not expect full coded answers. All I seek is advice and maybe snippets of code that helps me.

So, I am reading in about 900,000 words all stored in a arrayList. I need to count unique words using a sorted array (or arraylist) in java.

So far, I am simply looping over the given arrayList and use

```
Collections.sort(words);
```

and `Collections.binarySearch(words, wordToLook);` to achieve it like the following:

```
OrderedSet set = new OrderedSet();
    for(String a : words){
        if(!set.contains(a)){
            set.add(a);
        }
    }
```

and

```
public boolean contains(String word) {
    Collections.sort(uniqueWords);
    int result = Collections.binarySearch(uniqueWords, word);

    if(result<0){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

This code has a running time of about 60 seconds but I was wondering if there is any better way to do this because running a sort every time an element is added seems very inefficient (but of couse necessary if I were to use binary search).

Any sort of feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should never run a sort every time an element is added.

Comment: Yeah but what would an alternative be?

Comment: If you have a sorted array, you can count unique words in linear time by looping over the array just once. (Do you see how this is possible?) You don't have to use binary search.

Comment: As @irrelephant says, there is no need to sort the array each time an element is added. You can add the element in the proper place and avoid the sorting altogether (take a look at an algorithm called InsertionSort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are *required* to use a sorted array. That is ok, since you are (not yet) programming in the real world.

I will suggest two alternatives:

The first uses binary search (which you are using in your current code).

I would create a class that contains two fields: the word (a String) and the count for that word (an int). You will build a sorted array of these classes.

Start with an empty array and add to it as you read each word. For each word, do a binary search for the word in the array you are building. The search will either find the entry containing the word (and you will increment the count), or you will determine that the word is not yet in the array.

When your binary search ends without finding the word, you will create a new object to hold the word+count and add it to the array in the location where your search ended (be careful to make sure that your logic really puts it in the right spot to keep your list sorted). Of course, your count is set to 1 for new words.

Another alternative:

Read all of your words into a list and sort it. After sorting, all duplicates will be next to each other in the list.

You will walk down this sorted list once and create a list of word+count as you go. If the next word you see is the same as the last word+count, increment the count. If it is a new word, add a new word+count to your result list with count=1.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a sorted array. I would create a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is your word and the value is the count of the number of occurrences of the word. As you read each word, do something like this:

```
Integer count = map.get(word);
if (count == null) {
    count = 0;
}
map.put(word, count + 1);
```

Then just iterate over the map's entry set and do whatever you need to do with the counts.

If you know, or can estimate, the number of unique words then you should use this number in the HashMap constructor (so you don't grow the map many times).

If you use a sorted array, your run time cannot be better than proportional to NlogN (where N is the number of words in your list). If you use a HashMap, you can achieve a runtime that grows linearly with N (you save yourself the factor of logN).

Another advantage of using a Map is the memory used is proportional to the number of unique words, rather than the total number of words (assuming that you build the map while reading the words, rather than reading all words into a collection and then adding them to the map).

Comment: The thing is as much as I would love to use the map, I am forced to use a sorted array because it's a requirement..

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int countUnique(array) {
    if(array.length == 0) return 0;
    int count = 1;
    for i from 1 to array.length - 1 {
        if(!array[i].equals(array[i - 1])) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

This is a `O(N)` algorithm in pseudocode for counting the number of unique entries in a sorted array. The idea behind it is that we count the number of transitions between groups of equal elements. Then, the number of unique entries is the number of transitions plus one (for the first entry).

Hopefully you see how to apply this algorithm to your array after the elements are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use comparator to get unique values.

```
  List newList = new ArrayList(new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(words o1, words o2) {
            if(o1.equalsIgnoreCase(o2)){
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    });
```

Now count:

words - newList = no. of repeated values.

Hope this helps!!!!